# Express.js WebSocket ограничение на количество сообщений

Tags: express, websocket

Пишу игру на Express.js. Соответственно, общение между клиентом и сервером в основном происходит по WebSocket. И сейчас занялся вопросом защиты от намеренных атак со стороны хакеров. Хочу ограничить количество отправленных сообщений, чтобы нельзя было отправить больше 5 сообщений подряд, между каждым из которых разница менее 100 мс. Написал вот такой вот ограничитель:

```js
const checkDdos = (client, clientID, count, lastTime) => {
    if (Date.now() - lastTime < 100) {
        count += 1
        if (count === 5) {
            new S_LOGIN_FAILED(
                client,
                '',
                {
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Lost connection by many requests per time!',
                    isServerWorks: false
                }
            )
            client.close()
            logger.error(`LOST CONNECTION BY MANY REQUESTS BY TIME: ${clientID}`)
        }
        console.log(count)
    } else {
        count = 0
    }
    lastTime = Date.now()
    return {count, lastTime}
}
```

Все хорошо, он отключает пользователя, но зачастую не через 5 сообщений, а 10, 30, 50  из 1000. Так как сообщения я отправляю в цикле с клиента:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    let i = 0
    while (i < 1000){
        console.log('DDOS', i)
        new C_GET_MISSION_ROAD_MAP()
        i++
    }

}, [])
```

Может ли кто-то подсказать, как можно исправить эту задержку в отключении, чтобы отключало пользователя сразу через 5 сообщений и не давало дальше отправлять их?

Дополняю вопрос местом, где использую данную функцию:

```html
module.exports = (wss) => {
    wss.on('connection', function (client) {
        const clientID = UsersModel.socketConnectionClient(client)
        let messageCount = 0
        let lastTime = 0

        client.on('message', (message) => {
            try {
                const result = checkDdos(
                client, clientID, messageCount, lastTime
                )
                messageCount = result.count
                lastTime = result.lastTime
                if (messageCount < 5) {
                    message = JSON.parse(message)
                    handlerMessages(client,message)
                    loginManager.loginHandler(client,message)
                    if (
                    UsersModel.getUserData(message.username) 
                    || message.name === 'C_LOGIN' 
                    || message.name === 'C_PING'
                    ) {
                        gamesManager.usersHandler(client,message)
                        collectionManager.collectionHandler(client,message)
                        chatManager.chatHandler(client,message)
                        paramsManager.paramsHandler(client,message)
                        sevenDaysGiftsManager.sevenDaysGiftsHandler(
                            client,message
                        )
                        roadManager.roadHandler(client,message)
                        friendsManager.friendsHandler(client,message)
                        everyDayGiftManager.everyDayGiftManager(
                            client,message
                        )
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                logger.error('Error: ', error)
            }
        })

        client.on('close', function () {
            UsersModel.removeClient(clientID,GameModel)
            logger.info(`LOST CONNECTION: ${clientID}`)
            clearInterval(interval);
        });
        new S_PONG(client)

        interval = setTimeout(()=>{
            new S_PONG(client)
        },7000)
    });
}
```

Comment: Куда вы этот ограничитель вставили? Он по хорошему должен работать отдельно для каждого клиента. Так же не известны начальные значения и как вызывается функция

Comment: @SwaD , дополнил вопрос

Comment: Ограничитель работает для каждого отдельного пользователя. Как и счетчик.

Comment: Что показывает вам отладка? Визуально, все должно срабатывать. Может отключение, асинхронная операция и пока она срабатывает, прилетают еще сообщения? Они вообще с какой скоростью летят?

Comment: ну так как это типа защита от ддоса, то летят они с той скоростью, с которой их может выдавать цикл  (я его привел в вопросе) на клиенте. Соответсвенно, оно работает правильно, но опять же, не успевает сработать и отключить клиента до того, как он отправит еще какое то количество сообщений. То есть, просто не хватает скорости отключения. Я эти сообщения не обрабатываю уже, но они все равно то приходят и идет нагрузка на сервер. Отключение происходит, но не так быстро, как хотелось бы. Успевают просочиться еще какое то количество запросов

Comment: Мне кажется, что не получится. Запросы от пользака попадают в очередь и разгребаются последовательно. Пока вы добрались до 5го запроса, пришло уже 20 запросов. В любом случае, вы уже програмно защитили себя от выполнения тяжелых операций про ддосе по сокету

Comment: та вот тоже не знаю, вроде как и защитил, но в то же время порой и под 100 запросов успевает проскакивать, хотя они и не выполнятся, ибо поставил защиту на выполнение, но нагрузка все равно идет

Comment: Можно чуток переделать проверку, что бы не высчитывать каждый раз время, разницу и т.д. Создайте флаг дисконнекта и если его взвели, то уже никаких действий не делать. А то сейчас вы все лишние запросы чекаете, хотя пользака отправили на отключение

Comment: спасибо, учту это